# Looping through an array of times HTML 5 <video>

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, settimeout

I have an array of times that stores the paused times for a `<video>` element:

```
var pauseTimes = [0, 5, 12, 15];
```

I want to have a looping function that **starts** the video at 0 seconds and **puases** it at 5 seconds, then adds something to a `<div>`. Then I want the function to **start** the video at 5 seconds and **pause** it at 12 seconds and add something to a `<div>`. And so on and so forth.

I have this function that goes from 0 seconds to 5 seconds, then from 5 seconds to 12 seconds (etc. You get the picture):

```
  var b = 0;
  var vid = document.getElementById("video");
  function loopThrough () {
    vid.currentTime = pauseTimes[b];
    vid.play();
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
      if(this.currentTime >= pauseTimes[b]) {
        this.pause();
      }
    }, false);
    b++;
  }
```

But I do not know how to continuously loop through the array (i.e. from 0 to 5, 5 to 12, 12 to 15) and in between pausing and adding stuff to the div.

So far, I am using a for loop:

```
  var m = 0;
  function loopContinuously() {
    for (m = 0; m < pauseTimes.length-1; m++) {
      loopThrough();
      // Adding stuff to the div here
      m++;
    }
  }
```

It does what I want to do, but it skips very quickly through the time intervals. Is there a way to actually go through the video in the specified time interval (in the array) and add stuff to a `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

To create some delay between the time intervals, you can try using a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and increment the variable `b` in the "timeupdate" event.

Maybe a setup like this can help you:

- the video starts playing at 0
- pauses at 5 seconds for the millisecs given in the setTimeout function and then continues to 12
- pauses at 12 seconds for the millisecs given in the setTimeout function and then continues to 15
- pauses at 15 seconds for the millisecs given in the setTimeout function and then starts playing from 0

For example:

```
var pauseTimes = [0, 5, 12, 15];
var b = 0;
var vid = document.getElementById("video");

vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    if (this.currentTime >= pauseTimes[b]) {
        vid.pause();
        // Adding stuff to the div here
        b++;

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (b === pauseTimes.length) {
                // reset b
                b = 0;
                // reset the video
                vid.currentTime = 0;
                vid.load();
            } else {
                vid.play();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}, false);

vid.currentTime = pauseTimes[b++];
vid.play();
```

Comment: Is there really no other way than using a setTimeout?

Comment: @user5139637 This code also works without the using the `setTimeout`. I've added the setTimeout because you mentioned that it skips very quickly through the time intervals.